# Binding into another usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I just started working with WPF and I'm trying to wrap my head around the XAML Bindings.
After a lot of reading I thought I had an easy enough usecase to test my knowledge. But nada :-( I can't figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is the following:
I have Address-Objects:

```
public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses
{
    get
    {
        if (addresses == null)
        {
            addresses = new Repository<Address>().GetAll().ToList<Address>();
        }
        return addresses;
    }
}
```

which have Rental-Objects e.g.

```
address.Rentals
```

also as IList.
On my MainWidow I want to have 2 UserControls, one for the address and one for the rental information. If I click the Navigator on the address user control, I only want to see the rental records of the current address.

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="Swopt.Mira.WPFApp.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Swopt.Mira.WPFApp"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <sampleData:DataContext x:Key="testDataContext" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="White" DataContext="{StaticResource testDataContext}">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:RentalCustomer x:Name="rentalCustomer" Height="100"  />
        <local:Rentals Height="100" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Address**

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="Swopt.Mira.WPFApp.RentalCustomer" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="RentalCustomerUserControl">
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Firma1"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Firma1" Text="{Binding ElementName=collectionNavigator, Path=CurrentItem.Firma1}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadCollectionNavigator Grid.Row="1"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    x:Name="collectionNavigator"
                                    Source="{Binding Addresses}"
                                    />
</Grid>
```

**Rentals**

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="Swopt.Mira.WPFApp.Rentals" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="RentalsUserControl">
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="White" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="VertragsNr"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="VertragsNr" Text="{Binding ElementName=collectionNavigator2, Path=CurrentItem.VertragsNr}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadCollectionNavigator Grid.Row="1"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    x:Name="collectionNavigator2"
                                    Source="{Binding Rentals}" />
</Grid>
```

Essentially what I want to do is Bind the DataContext of UserControl2 (Rentals) to the CurrentItem of collectionNavigator in UserControl1 (Addresses)

But I can't figure out how. I tried many things, with Binding Path and RelativeSource but none seem to work. the only way I could get it to work was to copy the content of UserControl1 into my MainWindow.xaml, but then I can't reuse it.

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE >>>>>

Working solution from Sheridan.

**MainWindows**

```
...
<local:RentalCustomer x:Name="rentalCustomer" Height="400"  />
<local:Rentals Height="100" DataContext="{Binding CurrentAddress, ElementName=rentalCustomer}" />
```

**RentalCustomer.xaml**

```
...
<telerik:RadCollectionNavigator Grid.Row="1"
                                    Height="30"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    x:Name="collectionNavigator"
                                    Source="{Binding Addresses}"
                                    CurrentItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=CurrentAddress, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                    />
```

**RentalCustomer.xaml.cs**

```
public Address CurrentAddress
    {
        get { return (Address)GetValue(CurrentAddressProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentAddressProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentAddress.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentAddressProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentAddress", typeof(Address), typeof(RentalCustomer), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: Is there a SelectedItem property on the RadCollectionNavigator?

Comment: There is a CurrentItem property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can data bind the current item of a collection using the `"/"` `Binding` notation. Try something like this:

```
<UserControl Name="Control1" DataContext="{Binding SomeCollection}" />

<UserControl Name="Control2" DataContext="{Binding SomeCollection/}" />
```

`Binding SomeCollection/` means *bind to the current item of the `SomeCollection` collection*. To make this work, you may need to set the [`Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `True` on any container controls that you are selecting the current item in:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ... />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Without an `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property, the `"/"` `Binding` notation won't work. Instead, you could expose the selected item from the collection as a `DependencyProperty` on the relevant `UserControl`. Then you could do something like this:

```
<UserControl Name="Control2" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Control1}" />
```

Comment: I select the current item with the RadCollectionNavigator but unfortunatly this control doesn't expose IsSnchronizedWithCurrentItem.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the Rentals from your viewModel by binding the CurrentItem to your viewModel and expose the Rentals like this:

```
<telerik:RadCollectionNavigator CurrentItem={Binding CurrentItem} />

public Address CurrentItem
    {
       get; set;
    }

public IEnumerable<Rentals> Rentals
{
   get { return CurrentItem.Rentals; }

}
```